# java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetails

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-ldap

I managed to configure OAuth2 and ldap authorization. Created custom *LdapUser* by implementing *LdapUserDetails* and *CustomUserDetailsContextMapper* by implementing *UserDetailsContextMapper*. 
Eventually, I get access token when authorize by Active Directory username and password.

But the problem is, I cannot get my current logged user from *SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()* as it says 
**java.lang.String cannot be cast to LdapUser**

Below my security configure:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.authenticationProvider(adAuthenticationProvider())
        .ldapAuthentication()
    .userSearchBase("ldap.searchbase").userSearchFilter("ldap.filter").groupSearchFilter("ldap.groupsearch")
        .contextSource(contextSource())
        .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap.url"), "dc=smth,dc=com");
 }

  @Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adAuthenticationProvider() {
ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("smth.com","ldap.url");
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
    return provider;
}

@Bean
  public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
    return new CustomUserDetailsContextMapper();
  }
```

Custom LdapUser:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetails;
import java.util.Collection;

public class LdapUser implements LdapUserDetails
{
    private String commonName;
    private LdapUserDetails ldapUserDetails;

public LdapUser(LdapUserDetails ldapUserDetails) {
    this.ldapUserDetails = ldapUserDetails;
}

@Override
public String getDn() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getDn();
}

@Override
public void eraseCredentials() {

}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getAuthorities();
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return ldapUserDetails.isAccountNonExpired();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return ldapUserDetails.isAccountNonLocked();
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return ldapUserDetails.isCredentialsNonExpired();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return ldapUserDetails.isEnabled();
}
}
```

CustomUserDetailsContextMapper:
*I can print out context attributes successfully and I see that this is my logged user*

```
@Configuration
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {
private LdapUser ldapUser = null;
private String commonName;
private Boolean isCity;

@Override
public LdapUserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();
    LdapUserDetails ldapUserDetails = (LdapUserDetails) super.mapUserFromContext(ctx,username,authorities);
    return new LdapUser(ldapUserDetails);
}

@Override
public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {

    }
}
```

And now this is how i want to get custom LdapUser:

```
public LdapUser getCurrentLdapUser() {
    org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    LdapUser user = null;
    if (authentication != null) {
            user = ((LdapUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
    }
    return user;
}
```

After this function is called I get casting error. When I try to get principal name it returns - anonymousUser. I have no idea why it is not returning me LdapUser

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got the answer. Missed the basic things.
Since I did not configure Resource Server (**ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter**) every logged Active Directory user considered as anonymous. That is why, Security Context was returning String user instead of my custom Ldap user.

Here is an example *ResourceServerConfig* in case somebody will need:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

  @Override
  public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
resources
    .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
    .stateless(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .anonymous().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyAuthority("Authority_1","Authority_2")
    .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new UnauthorizedHandler())
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
  }

  @Bean
  public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
  }
}
```